# How to Manage Memory with Unmanaged C/C++ from C#.net?

Tags: c#, c++, c, memory-leaks, unmanaged-memory

Need some expert advice:

I have an unmanaged code from a 3rd party provider which is on C/C++ and I am writing a wrapper from C#.Net to get referred and use the respective methods. Since its unmanaged and there is a lot of places which has the memory leak and unmanaged code is not known to manage the memory what is the best solution for this kind of scenario?

I have the solution with PInvoke and Marshalling which bridges the Managed and Unmanaged with a knowledge of taking the memory management. But will GC takes care of this completely or is there still a gap which the memory should be released? Is there a solution from the .Net wrapper class i have a generic way to manage the memory for the unmanaged calls?

Comment: The managed and unmanaged heaps are completely separate as far as I'm aware. If your 3rd party code is so bad, I'd get rid of it!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172979/deleting-c-sharp-unsafe-pointers