# How to overwrite a point in memory in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to do have the following functionality:

```
var item0 = new Item();
var item1 = item0;
item0 = null;

Console.WriteLine(item1 == null); // true
```

So I'd be overwriting the memory that item0 and item1 point to.
I figured maybe I could do this with pointers..? However, when I tried declaring an item pointer:

```
Item* itemPointer;
```

i got an error. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know of any language where the syntax you proposed would work - and if it did it would introduce a lot of hard to find bugs

Comment: you can free a pointer using Marshaling but if that pointer is owned else where you would most likely just have an horrible death. [I guess you could check this for a start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172979/deleting-c-sharp-unsafe-pointers)

Comment: I am mostly curious as to *why* you want to do this? What is the purpose of directly modifying memory this way (and giving up all the safety the runtime provides)?

Comment: @UnholySheep: My guess is he doesn't want any garbage left over in memory.

Comment: I totally agree with @UnholySheep, but it looks to me he just want to make a new copy of the item rather than having a clone.

Comment: if `item1` was `Func<Item> item1 = () => item0;` then `Console.WriteLine(item1() == null);` would return `true`

Comment: @UnholySheep in summary: i have written a load classes which are immutable. i want to put some instances of these classes in dictionaries, and have other objects use information from the stuff in the dictionaries. however, i occassionally want to reassign the stuff in the dictionary, but i would also want to keep the references of my other objects up to date (hence my question). i think the easiest solution will be to make the necessary things settable, therefore the dictionary values stay the same the whole time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since C# 7 You can use [Ref Locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns):

```
var item0 = new Item();
ref var item1 = ref item0;
item0 = null;

Console.WriteLine(item1 == null); // true  
// THIS WORKS!
```

[Ref returns and ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) have mainly been introduced to avoid copying large structs in time sensitive scenarios like gaming where large arrays of vectors have to be processed. I don't see the advantage in using them with reference types. They tend to make the code hard to understand, thus I would restrict their use to exceptional and rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item0
{
   get{return item0;}
   set
   {
     item0 = value;
     item1 = item0;
   }
}
```

Something like this will overwrite the value of item1 every time the value of item0 changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are no local aliases/references in C#
However there is a `ref` keyword for arguments:

```
static void RefClean(ref String arg){
    arg = null;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var test = "Hello";
    Console.WriteLine(test == null);
    RefClean(ref test);
    Console.WriteLine(test == null);
}
```

---

For pointers you need the `unsafe` keyword, and you have to use unmanaged types only (primitive types and structures built from them), which rules out your case with objects/references. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types for some overview.